# Benefits of adding a new table

Tags: sql, database-design

I have a theory question. Let's say I have a table named "Worker" for people working in an office, and one of the columns would be "Role". I can add a constraint (CHECK IN ("director", "HR", "Secretary", "PA", etc...). What would be the benefits of creating a separate new table ("Roles") with all possible roles and and an id to relate both tables?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms

Comment: Easier to maintain, for one thing. When a role is added or removed (or its name is changed), you won't have to change check constraints - which you may also forget to do. Easier to write queries where you need results by role, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `check` constraint would be written as:

```
(CHECK IN role ('director', 'HR', 'Secretary', 'PA', ...)
```

The advantages of storing the roles in a separate table.  Here are some:

- You have a list of all roles that can be accessed by anyone else.
- You can provide additional data about the role -- translation to another language, abbreviation, salary grade, and so on.
- Adding or modifying an existing role only requires changes to *data*, not to the structure of the database.
- You can provide metadata, such as date created and who created the role.

Comment: I would also add versioning for the additional data

Answer (score 1):

> What would be the benefits of creating a separate new table ("Roles") with all possible roles and and an id to relate both tables?

Here are some off the top of my head:

- Any additional roles would be a change to the table definition rather than a standard INSERT to a table
- You can use the data in the table to drive UI items like list boxes
- If you rename/add/delete a role you'd have to drop the constraint, update all records in the `Worker` table, and re-add the new constraint
- You can add ancillary data about a role without adding columns to `Worker`
- You would have to replicate the constraint in layers outside of the DB